# sqlite SELECT returns all records when querying a column for a value with the same name as the column

Tags: sqlite

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.6.21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(foo text);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ("foo");
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ("bar");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo="foo";
foo
bar
sqlite>
```

It seems that the query treats "foo" as a reference to the name of the column, rather than as a string constant.  How do I get this query to only return foo, not bar?  Are there options besides renaming the column?

Comment: not to be trivial but.. no upvote on the answer?

Comment: Requires 15 reputation.  Sorry.  First time user.

Comment: There ya go. Sorry bout that.

Comment: Now i do feel trivial. lol. glad i could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Sqlite3 Keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo='foo';
```

use single quotes.